# Comparison of metadata styles available in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-10.0, metadata

I'm looking for an overview of the differences between the editable metadata styles available in ArcCatalog. Were the diferent styles developed for use by specific groups of users? Are there any advantages/disadvantages of using one style over another? What are the specific differences in the available fields?

Complete answers to these questions might be too lengthy for this forum. A few sentances with links to pertinant resorces would be a great help. The ESRI help is severely lacking in this area (unless I've missed something).

I'm using ArcGIS 10, which seems to have fewer options than earlier versions had, so I'm mainly interested in the four options built into ArcCAtalog, plus the FGDC editor add-in. However, more is always better. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The [Metadata standards and styles](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003t00000008000000.htm) help topic is a great place to start and breaks down the different styles.

Comment: Thanks Swingley, for pointing that out. I swear I looked over that entire help section, and still missed that particular article. So, +1 to you. There is a lot of useful info there, but it still doesn't really answer my question. I'm trying to decide which metadata format will match my specific needs. While the old "ESRI-ISO" metadata format might not have been perfect, the new "Item Description" format looks a little TOO dumbed down for my needs. I'm trying to keep it simple and use something that's built into Arc. Wondering what style others have settled on.